# finding points of discontinuity in a case defined function

Tags: calculus, limits, continuity

Find all points of discontinuity (if any) for:
$$f(x) =
\begin{cases}
\frac{16}{x^2},  & \text{if $x \ge 2$} \\[2ex]
3x - 2, & \text{if $x < 2$}
\end{cases}$$
what i got is:

$f(2)= \frac{16}{2^2}= 4$

and also the limit as x approches 2 exists and is equal to 4
**therefore my answer is: *this case defind function has no point of discontinuity***

i am extremely unsure if this is the correct answer, please correct me if i am wrong, thanks!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Yes, you are right.
Note that the only discontinuity point for $\dfrac{16}{x^2}$ on the $\mathbb{R}$; is the point $x=0$.
But notice that $0 < 2$; 
so it only suffices to check out the continuity at $x=2$;
as you have been mentioned, we have:

$$ 
\lim_{x \rightarrow 2^-}f(x) 
= 
3 \cdot 2 -2 
= 
4 
= 
\dfrac{16}{2^2} 
= 
\lim_{x \rightarrow 2^+}f(x) 
\ 
, 
$$

so we can conclude that this function is continuous every where.